# how to debug futex congestion in system

Tags: kernel

I have perl multithreaded script ("assp antispam proxy") that uses multiple perl libraries. On one of my servers after about 2 hours script starts to make huge number of futexed which consumes a lot of cpu power. On other servers this not occurs so it is probably starts happening after some race condition for server resource. Asking developer for any information how to debug this issue meet with no response.

using strace or sysdig I see that this perl script starts to make huge number of futex requests. 
How can I debug this and find out on what file all those kernel futex are made? I've tried sysdig and oprofile but did not found any way to check it.

10 seconds running strace:

```
# strace -f -p 6130 -c
Process 6130 attached with 8 threads - interrupt to quit
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 57.44    3.265528       16493       198           nanosleep
 28.53    1.622291       19313        84           poll
  8.54    0.485535           1    787123    169255 futex
  5.28    0.300018       75005         4           restart_syscall
  0.21    0.012001        2400         5           select
  0.00    0.000209           0     35751           sched_yield
 ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    5.685582                823355    169273 total
```

small example of these futexes:

```
    75853 13:09:36.167879875 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743049
75855 13:09:36.167880152 2 perl (6248) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=40961 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75856 13:09:36.167880436 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
75857 13:09:36.167880702 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
75858 13:09:36.167881606 0 perl (6154) < futex res=1
75863 13:09:36.167882554 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75865 13:09:36.167882949 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=2
75866 13:09:36.167883026 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A58 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75869 13:09:36.167883226 2 perl (6248) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=40961 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75870 13:09:36.167883231 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
75873 13:09:36.167883503 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75877 13:09:36.167884305 0 perl (6154) < futex res=1
75885 13:09:36.167885569 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75887 13:09:36.167885810 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75888 13:09:36.167885945 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75890 13:09:36.167886138 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743051
75891 13:09:36.167886404 2 perl (6248) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=40961 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75892 13:09:36.167886585 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
75894 13:09:36.167887449 0 perl (6154) < futex res=1
75896 13:09:36.167888690 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75897 13:09:36.167888969 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75899 13:09:36.167889092 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75900 13:09:36.167889194 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A58 op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=2
75902 13:09:36.167889326 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A58 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75903 13:09:36.167889510 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75904 13:09:36.167889619 0 perl (6154) < futex res=-11(EAGAIN)
75905 13:09:36.167889716 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743053
75906 13:09:36.167889945 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
75907 13:09:36.167889977 2 perl (6248) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=40961 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75908 13:09:36.167890792 0 perl (6154) < futex res=1
75910 13:09:36.167892302 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75911 13:09:36.167892572 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75912 13:09:36.167892712 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75913 13:09:36.167892744 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743055
75915 13:09:36.167893152 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
75916 13:09:36.167893352 0 perl (6154) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=2 pgft_min=224301 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75917 13:09:36.167894180 2 perl (6248) < futex res=1
75921 13:09:36.167894912 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
75922 13:09:36.167895247 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75924 13:09:36.167895461 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
75925 13:09:36.167895929 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743057
75926 13:09:36.167895988 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
75927 13:09:36.167896092 2 perl (6248) < futex res=-11(EAGAIN)
75929 13:09:36.167896259 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
75930 13:09:36.167896312 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=2
75931 13:09:36.167896547 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75933 13:09:36.167896605 2 perl (6248) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=40961 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75939 13:09:36.167897494 0 perl (6154) < futex res=1
75944 13:09:36.167899107 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75945 13:09:36.167899365 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75946 13:09:36.167899498 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75947 13:09:36.167899541 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743059
75950 13:09:36.167900094 0 perl (6154) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=2 pgft_min=224301 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75952 13:09:36.167900811 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
75953 13:09:36.167901474 2 perl (6248) < futex res=1
75958 13:09:36.167903232 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
75959 13:09:36.167903727 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=2
75960 13:09:36.167903788 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75961 13:09:36.167903875 2 perl (6248) < futex res=-11(EAGAIN)
75963 13:09:36.167904047 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
75964 13:09:36.167904106 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A58 op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=2
75967 13:09:36.167904348 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A58 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75968 13:09:36.167904374 2 perl (6248) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=40961 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75971 13:09:36.167905247 0 perl (6154) < futex res=1
75973 13:09:36.167905490 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743061
75978 13:09:36.167905988 0 perl (6154) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=2 pgft_min=224301 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
75983 13:09:36.167906745 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75985 13:09:36.167906986 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
75990 13:09:36.167907588 2 perl (6248) < futex res=1
75992 13:09:36.167907788 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
75993 13:09:36.167907927 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
75998 13:09:36.167909046 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
76002 13:09:36.167909432 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A20 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
76004 13:09:36.167909584 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A58 op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=2
76005 13:09:36.167909674 0 perl (6154) < futex res=0
76008 13:09:36.167909846 2 perl (6248) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=40961 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
76009 13:09:36.167909969 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A58 op=129(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE) val=1
76011 13:09:36.167910704 0 perl (6154) < futex res=1
76012 13:09:36.167910946 0 perl (6154) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=128(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG) val=115743063
76015 13:09:36.167911454 0 perl (6154) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=2 pgft_min=224301 vm_size=990864 vm_rss=669216 vm_swap=0
76020 13:09:36.167912232 2 perl (6248) < futex res=0
76022 13:09:36.167912491 2 perl (6248) > futex addr=7F51EF8E0A5C op=133(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_WAKE_OP) val=1
```

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux you can try [systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap). It requires a bit of preparation beforehand. Consult the [online documentation](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/documentation.html) on this regard.

There you'll find [an example](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/futexcontentionsect.html) targeting [fast userspace mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) system calls, reproduced below for completenes.

It is worth noting (from both sources cited above) that:

From the Wikipedia article:

> A properly programmed futex-based lock will not use system calls except when the lock is contended; since most operations do not require arbitration between processes, this will not happen in most cases

From the `systemtap` documentation:

> Simply put, futex contention occurs when multiple processes are trying to access the same lock variable at the same time. This can result in a poor performance because the lock serializes execution; one process obtains the lock while the other processes must wait for the lock variable to become available again.

The script from systemtap's example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap

# This script tries to identify contended user-space locks by hooking
# into the futex system call.

global FUTEX_WAIT = 0 /*, FUTEX_WAKE = 1 */
global FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG = 128 /* linux 2.6.22+ */
global FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME = 256 /* linux 2.6.29+ */

global lock_waits # long-lived stats on (tid,lock) blockage elapsed time
global process_names # long-lived pid-to-execname mapping

probe syscall.futex.return {  
  if (($op & ~(FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME)) != FUTEX_WAIT) next
  process_names[pid()] = execname()
  elapsed = gettimeofday_us() - @entry(gettimeofday_us())
  lock_waits[pid(), $uaddr] <<< elapsed
}

probe end {
  foreach ([pid+, lock] in lock_waits) 
    printf ("%s[%d] lock %p contended %d times, %d avg us\n",
            process_names[pid], pid, lock, @count(lock_waits[pid,lock]),
            @avg(lock_waits[pid,lock]))
}
```

You can also try using [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-5.07/) on your perl program to pinpoint the misbehaving code.

Comment: I believe that systemtap script can only pinpoint process name (and pid) and fact there is huge number of futex calls - both of which I already know. I does not provide any insight into on what resource (file) this futex calls were made on.

Comment: That is because it is just an example.

Comment: Worked great on ubuntu 18 debugging qemu, thanks!